# Does continuity of a real function require completeness of the Reals?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, real-numbers

It appears intuitively obvious to me that the definition of a real function that is continuous requires the completeness of the reals. But, for some reason my real analysis professor simply dismissed this question without further explanation.

Comment: Why does it seem to need the completeness? You can easily talk about continuous functions $\mathbb{Q}\to \mathbb{Q}$. Some of them have extensions to continuous functions $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, others don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your definition of continuity is an $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition, then one can have continuous functions from any metric space (that is, a space with a well-defined distance function). As mentioned in the comments, $\mathbb{Q}$ is a metric space with the normal metric.

Then the proof that $f(x) = x$ or $f(x) = x^2$ are continuous are the exact same, $\epsilon$-$\delta$-wise, over $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R}$.

However, there are interesting things lurking just beneath the surface. For instance, the only continuous functions from $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{Q}$ are constant functions. (But there are very many continuous functions from $\mathbb{Q}$ to $\mathbb{R}$). The reason for this has something to do with the completeness of $\mathbb{R}$, and more generally that there are enough reals in the metric topology for the real line to be connected.

If you were to ask your professor for a bit more about the differences between continuous functions from $\mathbb{Q}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ and from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{Q}$ (and if your professor is a nice guy or girl), then this should spark a conversation about topics with buzzwords "connectedness, topology, open and closed sets," and perhaps even "compactness."

Comment: So far I have never encountered continuous functions that weren't real so I think that was the source of my error. But, I now realize that the concept of continuity can be generalized beyond real functions.